# Magento 2.3.4 REST Api integration with stock using own API module

Tags: rest, integration, magento2

I would like to synchronize the stock with my supplier.
I am using Magento 2.3.4, supplier uses other system.
To get list of sku and quantity I have to use code like this:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://abcd.systim.com/jsonAPI.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true); //(POST method)
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'act=listPQuantities'.
           '&token=6aed003dc54951c043f8d1ad4b4804a2a8a40f'); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
$data = json_decode($result,true); // values
 
if($dane['error']['code']>0) die($dane['error']['message']); //error check 

foreach($dane['result'] as $result)
{
   echo "Source name: " . $result['source_name'] . ", product id: " . $result['product_id'] .
       ", product name: " . $result['product_name'] . ", ean: " . $result['ean'] . 
       ", prodcut sku: " . $result['product_sku'] . ", quantity: " . $result['quantity'] . "<br>";
}
```

Next I want to convert data to JSON like this:

```
{
  "sourceItems": [{
    "sku": "VAL715623",
    "source_code": "default",
    "quantity": 0,
    "status": 1
  }
```

Then I want to send it to Magento using POST method by

```
rest/default/V1/inventory/source-items
```

I need custom cron job to do it automatically.

I try to run this code but in not ideal

```
<?php
namespace Vagwan\InventorySync\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
use Vagwan\InventorySync\Api\InventorySyncInterface;

class InventorySync implements InventorySyncInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $curl;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Curl $curl
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->curl = $curl;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Fetch data from third-party API
        $username = 'api_user';
        $password = 'pass';
        $url = 'https://linker.stock.com/api/productstocks';

        $this->curl->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $this->curl->addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password"));
        $this->curl->get($url);

        $response = $this->curl->getBody();

        if ($response === false) {
            return 'Error: ' . $this->curl->getError();
        } else {
            $inventoryData = json_decode($response, true);

            // Loop through $inventoryData and update Magento inventory accordingly
            foreach ($inventoryData as $item) {
                $code128 = $item['code128']; // Assuming code128 corresponds to SKU in Magento
                $quantity = $item['quantity'];

                // Implement logic to update Magento inventory for product with $code128
                // Perform necessary Magento inventory update operations here
                // Example: Use Magento Inventory API or direct database operations
            }

            return 'Inventory synced successfully!';
        }
    }
}
```